# Require a class from another class - php

Tags: php, require

I'm learning PHP. And I have a problem that I can't understand. This my situation:

I have a directory called Lib. This is the structure of my directory:

[image]

In the directory database I wrote a class QueryBuilder.

```
<?php

//require '../Task';

class QueryBuilder{

    public function selectAll($table,$pdo){

        $statement = $pdo->prepare("Select * from {$table}");

        $statement->execute();

        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'Task');
    }
}
?>
```

In the class I use an external class Task that I wrote before and that I use in the statement return.

```
return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'Task');
```

This is the Task class:

```
<?php

    class Task{
        
        protected $description;
        protected $completed=false;
    
        public function __contruct($description){
    
            $this->description = $description;
    
        }
    
    
        public function getDescription(){
    
            return $this->description;
    
        }
    
    
        public function getCompleted(){
    
            return $this->completed;
        }
    
    }
    
    
    ?>
```

So I thought that If I wanted to use the Task class I had to import the file. So at the beginning of the my class `QueryBuilder` I wrote the require statement.

```
require '../Task';
```

The problem is that when I run my class I get this error:

```
Warning: require(../Task): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive - Sogei\Desktop\php-learning\php-course\Lib\database\QueryBuilder.php on line 3

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../Task' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive - Sogei\Desktop\php-learning\php-course\Lib\database\QueryBuilder.php on line 3
```

Without the require statement instead the class works.

How is it possible? Is not necessary import the Task class?

Comment: You forgot the `.php` extention. You also have to initiate the class with `new Task()`. Otherwise you can never use it. My tip: look at [`traits`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). Far easier to use than initiating class inside class, they use the same scope and are reusable.

Comment: Thanks Michel you are rigth when you say that I had to use .php, but the problem is the same., Also i i use require '../Task.php' the code dosen't work. I get the same errror.

Comment: Could you provide the code, where you instantiate the QueryBuilder. Are you using the Task in the same Script? This would explain, why you don't get an error.

Answer (score 0):

It is more usefull to use dirname. For exemple in your case :

```
require dirname(__FILE__, 2) . '/Task.php';
```

It will search the file in second level of your arbo of your class.

In an other end, you can use an autoload called by your frontend script.

And for the error, 'Task' doesn't exist. It's 'Task.php' witch exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is the same. I tried to use require dirname(__FILE__, 2) . '/Task.php'; but the code dosen't work. If I cancel the require statement the class works fine and this, for me, is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `require __DIR__ . /../Task.php` you're also missing the .php File extension. If it's not working, try to use it in the constructor. Also notice, that you should work with an autoloader and namespaces, it's pretty easy to configure.

Comment: You are rigth with th extension, but the code dosen't work with yor solution. The problem is tha I don't understand why without the require statement my class works...

Comment: try to put it into the constructor and make: require_once instead of require

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, move one directory backward and require task.php

```
require '../Task.php';
```